# ItextSharp PDF Header Footer Repetition Issue

Tags: c#, html, itext, html-to-pdf

I have used Itextsharp from Nuget Package and parsed HTML to PDF and passed Bytes to frontend of website and showing the PDF on iframe.

Firstly i had two separate HTML for the PDF,i.e., one for the header and other one for the body. When i used to parse the HTML to PDF, the issue which came across was the repetition of header. Header is works fine on the first page but on the second page header and body overlap each other. I tried a lot by overriding OnStartPage and OnEndPage function but nothing worked.

Secondly I tried header through C# code and body through HTML but that also seems not be not working and having the same issue.

I think the main issue is with page break(correct me if i am wrong). If any of you from the community can help me out please go forward. I am sharing the code and really appreciate all the help.

Please let me know if any code is missing. I need header on every page that need to be consistent but with dynamic content.

```
         using System;
         using System.Collections.Generic;
         using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;

         namespace WebApi.Controllers
         {
             using iTextSharp.text;
             using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
             using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
             using iTextSharp.tool.xml.css;
             using iTextSharp.tool.xml.html;
             using iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser;
             using iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css;
             using iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.end;
             using iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html;
             using System.IO;
             using System.Text;
             using System.Web.Mvc;

             public class PDFGenerateController : Controller
             {
                 [NonAction]
                 public byte[] Index(IModel iModel)
                 {
                     // get HTML for body
                     var html = GetHtml(iModel, false); 
                     byte[] bytes;
                     Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);

                  using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, memoryStream);
                         AddImageToHeader pageEventHandler = new AddImageToHeader(GetHtml(processedData, true)); // get html for header right side
                         IHeaderFooter iHeaderFooter = new IHeaderFooter(GetHtml(processedData, true)); // get html for header right side

                         writer.PageEvent = iHeaderFooter;
                         writer.PageEvent = pageEventHandler;
                         writer.PageEvent = new HeaderFooterAdd(iModel);
                         writer.CloseStream = false;

                         pdfDocument.Open();

                         HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
                         htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                         ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
                         cssResolver.AddCssFile("C:/pdf.css", true);

                         IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext,
                             new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDocument, writer)));

                         XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
                         XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);
                         xmlParser.Parse(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)));
                         pdfDocument.Close();

                         bytes = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
                         memoryStream.Close();
                     }

                     return bytes;
                 }

                 public class iHeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
                 {

                     private readonly string _html;


                     public iHeaderFooter(string html)
                     {
                         _html = html;
                     }

                     public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
                     {
                         var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
                         XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider =
                             new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
                         CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
                         HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
                         htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                         PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
                         HtmlPipeline html1 = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);

                         CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html1);
                         XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
                         XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
                         p.Parse(new StringReader(_html));

                        //for page break but didn't worked out
                         /*using (TextReader htmlViewReader = new StringReader(_html))
                         {
                             using (var htmlWorker = new HeaderFooterAdd.HTMLWorkerExtended(document))
                             {
                                 htmlWorker.Open();
                                 htmlWorker.Parse(htmlViewReader);
                             }
                         }*/

                         base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
                     }
                 }
             }

            // Add logo image to header left side
             public class AddImageToHeader : PdfPageEventHelper
             {
                 private readonly string _html;

                 public AddImageToHeader(string html)
                 {
                     _html = html;
                 }

                 public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
                 {
                     iTextSharp.text.Image imghead = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:/logo.png");
                     imghead.ScaleAbsolute(189f, 79f);
                     imghead.SetAbsolutePosition(30, 0);

                     PdfContentByte cbhead = writer.DirectContent;
                     PdfTemplate tp = cbhead.CreateTemplate(320, 100);
                     tp.AddImage(imghead);

                     cbhead.AddTemplate(tp, 0, 830 - 95);

                     base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
                 }
             }

             public class HeaderFooterAdd : PdfPageEventHelper
             {
                //C# Header 
                 public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
                 {
                     PdfPTable tbHeader = new PdfPTable(2);
                     tbHeader.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
                     tbHeader.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                     tbHeader.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
                     tbHeader.DefaultCell.Top = 100;
                     tbHeader.DefaultCell.Bottom = 100;
                     tbHeader.AddCell(new Paragraph());

                     Phrase datePhrase = new Phrase(new Chunk($"{"Label"}: {"Text"}\n", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));

                     PdfPCell _cell = new PdfPCell(datePhrase);
                     _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

                     _cell.BorderWidthBottom = 0f;
                     _cell.BorderWidthLeft = 0f;
                     _cell.BorderWidthTop = 0f;
                     _cell.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
                     _cell.PaddingTop = 45f;
                     _cell.ExtraParagraphSpace = 2f;

                     tbHeader.AddCell(_cell);
                     tbHeader.AddCell(new Paragraph());

                     tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, 
 writer.PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin) + 40,
                         writer.DirectContent);
                 }

                //for page break but didn't worked out
                 /*public class HTMLWorkerExtended : HTMLWorker
                 {
                     public HTMLWorkerExtended(IDocListener document) : 
 base(document)
                     {

                     }
                     public override void StartElement(string tag, 
IDictionary<string, string> str)
                     {
                         if (tag.Equals("newpage"))
                             document.Add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
                         else
                             base.StartElement(tag, str);
                     }
                 }*/
         }
```

Comment: Please use iText 7 + pdfHTML instead, they are also on NuGet. iText 5 is end of life.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Can you please help me out if i can implement the same with Itext5 or any other Library ?

Comment: I cannot help you, I don't write code, but maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: There are a number of issues in your code architecture: **A** You add content in `OnStartPage`. iText developers have stated again and again that you must not add content in that method in any way. **B** You add content to the `Document` instance parameter in a page event callback. iText developers have stated again and again that you shall not do that; if you want to add content in page event callbacks, do so via the `PdfWriter` parameter. **C** You use the `XmlWorker` both for the page content and in page events. This cannot work as the `XmlWorker` stores its states by thread.